# How to test objects depending on complex data structure?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, nunit

I'm struggling with a more theoretical question. How can you test something that operates with quite complex structure?

For example, I have a converter that converts a multi-level data structure. So I divide this conversion to more sub-converters and one "master" converter, so I can test them separately. Tests for sub-converters are quite easy, because they depend only on primitive data types or low level complexity data structures.

But problem is how to test the "master" converter, which requires all these sub-converters and also complex data structure to test overall result.

To example, I need to convert data object, which has on first level some primitive types and one complex type. This complex type consists of primitive types and again one complex type which than finally represents only primitive types. That means 3 levels of nesting logically, or 6 in real, because there could be some field objects (Lists ect.) contain these complex types.

And to prepare testing data for this complex structure is not nice. Not even mention I've heard a statement once that anytime you have to do a complex set up in tests means you are doing something wrong. I know it's not a dogma, but the feeling about this is not good.

So am I trying to test something that shouldn't be tested? Or am I trying the wrong approach for creating tests?

[Edited]

Example:

```
Type1

 - int number1
 - string name
 - List<Type2> object1

Type2

 - int number
 - string name
 - List<Type2> object2
```

Than you can have three sub-converters, number, string and Type2 converters and one master converter for Type1 object.

Object2 is the last nested object. So it is logically only three level structure. But to reconstruct this, you have to do more than just creating three objects with some properties.

You have to create List objects for this and populate them with at least one object so subconverters can do their work.

Comment: Is your converter using recursion to convert your data? If that is so, your test only needs to look at one level of test data. By induction, your test could be seen to support multiple levels if it works for only 2.

Comment: No, the master converter is not using any recursion. One of the subconverters will probably do, because some of data objects in lower levels can be present in others or nested to each other, but not the top one.

Comment: If that's the kind of object you're processing, then I wouldn't count building it as "complex set up". It's not clear how the subconverters are involved, though; do you have to do anything in the test to orchestrate them? Could you give a [mcve]?

Comment: I've added some example of data structure